# Reputation recalculation and overall ranking change

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-leagues

Before the [recalculation update](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) I was pretty close to being in the top 1% overall (my actual rating was top 2% overall). I was expecting to slide further away from 1% since I have asked one question with three upvotes but the [opposite happened and I'm in the the top 0.97%](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31/30697#30697). Before the update I needed 27,330 to hit the top 1% and as of today I have 27,288.

I'm not complaining but I am confused; can someone explain what happened? Did more users register?

Comment: Users register every day, so to answer that question: probably yes. But what's confusing about having more rep than necessary to reach 1% and therefore... being higher than 1%? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Before the update I was top 2%. After the update, top 1%. I only gained 15 points and even without the update my new point amount wasn't enough to be in the top 1%. What is unclear?

Comment: "* users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues" ... (you can figure out exact number of users moving into "tracked in  the leagues" category to push you to 0.97% if you really want to)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that explanation makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @Alexei Would you consider posting it as an answer with link to the source?